# Tor and app control solutions

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Tor looks very advanced in network intelligence, but before the target, the last, the first node, the firewall, the proxy, there's the computer himself !

What if Tor is blacklisted from a computer-installed app control software ?

For example Sophos can block it and i haven't found any solutions (considering the computer is protected from USB Boot and BIOS access, so using the controlled OS)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

to make it as short & simple as possible: if this all is blocked/controlled, the solution is to use an other computer!

- as this all is blocked and you don't have access to it, i guess it is not your hardware.
- perhaps the owner of the hardware has good reasons to restrict the usage of his hardware.
  if not, you can ask him to loosen the restrictions (e.g. to use your own liveOS with your data/settings). - this also may have advantages for the hardware-owner, because he does not need an installed OS, worry about it's maintenance and probably save the hard-disk.
- i doubt you have the freedom to choose your internet connection as long as everything else is controlled but if so, you can use [Orbot](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orbot/), [Onion Pi](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/overview) or any other Tor-router/-proxy to route your traffic over Tor.
  but there are tons of things you have to observe (but maybe can't) and can go wrong, so i wouldn't recommend this.
- last but not least:
  on such an highly controlled environment (not by yourself) i wouldn't do anything sensitive, even if there were TorBrowser preinstalled. - who knows what is recorded or leaked by the OS, intentionally or by accident (malware, backdoors etc.)!?

Comment: I can't use an other computer, the AD reject all stranger computer, i haven't tester Orbot but if he need a .exe it will be the same, and Tor isn't preinstalled but i can't say if it's spyed or not, and we cannot always ask the network administrator to make an exception specialy for us

Comment: @Pingo-power if all stranger computers are blocked, perhaps use an other network?!? **||** [Orbot](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orbot/) is an android-app! it provides a "Tor-secured" network access, that's why it is contained in one bullet with the choice of your internet connection. **||** that's what my last bullet is about: even **IF** Tor were preinstalled (keyword honeypot), i would strongly advise to NOT use it, because you shouldn't trust neither the admin nor the OS/setup.

Comment: Another network ? I don't talk about my mobile phone he's fine. I want to access internet without censure on this network. And be relieved, there not any Tor preinstalled. If it was, so i can run it. Here the topic is about can't run Tor, so :)

Comment: @Pingo-power you don't get my points, please try to understand them: have you ever heard about [tethering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering)? - this is the other way round to what you mentioned in the last comment. **||** if the network access is restricted to the admins computers and they are restricted to the preinstalled OS, it simply won't work! - see the short & simple answer in the very first sentence. **||** once again: also **IF** Tor were preinstalled you **CAN** run it, but you definitely **should NOT**!!!

Comment: So i can't use Tor if there's a software who block the Tor opening